# Fetching layout details from intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i have a small query,
Suppose we start an activity using intents

```
startActivity(intent);
```

and a new screen opens up with content in it,like buttons and text fields
I just need to know if its possible to fetch the details about the layout and its contents.

I think its not possible, but just wanted to get a proper confirmation.

Comment: What details do you need to get from the second layout and why?

Comment: I needed to automate a button press from the second layout, and that got me thinking. Its more out of curiosity now, i'll find a different approach, but still just wanted to find out if its possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do this. And (from comments) no, it's not possible to "click" a button from a separate `Activity`. What you can do, however, is this:

```
// Calling code:
intent.putExtra(getPackageName() + ".click_me", R.id.your_button); // getPackageName() is for best practices
startActivity(intent);

// In your Activity:
Intent intent = getIntent(); // Get the Intent we used to launch this
int buttonToClick = intent.getIntExtra(getPackageName() + ".click_me", 0); // Get the integer
if (buttonToClick != 0) { // If it's 0, we didn't specify it
    View toClick = findViewById(buttonToClick); // Find the View
    if (toClick != null && toClick instanceof Button) { // If the View exists, and is a Button..
        ((Button) toClick).performClick(); // ..then click it
    }
}
```

You provide the `Intent` that starts the `Activity` with an integer. This integer represents a `View` (more specifically, a `Button`). Once the `Activity` receives it, it finds the matching `View`, checks if its a `Button`, then performs a click action on it.

This way, you're just passing the integer ID of an item to click, and your opened `Activity` just handles the rest.

Comment: Ya, this is actually good, but i cant use it, I ma using intents for adding event to calendar, but for custom activities this actually will work very well

Comment: @Eric could u please explain ur code bit more? I like the concept but not really getting it.

Comment: I've added a brief description of how this code works; hope that covers it well enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents using getChildAt()

```
for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount(); ++i) {
    View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)v).getChildAt(i);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, this only works for the current `Activity`. The OP wants to reach into another `Activity`'s layout details.

Comment: Could u pls elaborate on this?